# How do you populate a dropdown box using data from another model so that all rows are taken as options in yii?

Tags: php, yii, dropdownbox

I'm using version 1.1.14 of yii.

My VIEW file has

`<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'estado', CHtml::listData(Estado::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'estado')); ?>`

I have a model called Estado which was generated from a table with only 2 fields ID as PK and estado where I have my data. Which has 3 rows Active, Inactive, Prospecting.

So far the code only shows the last row of that table, ignoring the first 2.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm using larry ulmans example from his book. I wonder why it would work in his book, but not on my system. <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'project_id', CHtml::listData(Project::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name')); ?>

Comment: can you send me a print_r of the following please
print_r(Estado::model()->findAll()->getAttributes());

Comment: Also, is the PK field called ID or id?

Comment: THanks LIAM. That was the issue. The ID field did not exist. Whoops.

Answer (score 1):

for the dropdown list you can pass a normal array :

```
$data = array(
   'number1',
   'number2',
   'number3',
);
```

or an array with key => value

```
$data = array(
   7 => 'number7',
   2 =>'number2',
   4 =>'number4',
);
```

`Chtml::listData()` will only help you make that array avalable for the function

however if you need to make a combination of models ( or arrays) you have to do that manually using array concatenation functions such as `CMap::mergeArray()`